# Paste multiple pages from an other dokuwiki

Tags: dokuwiki

I copy pasted pages and datas from my local dokuwiki(windows) to an ftp dokuwiki (linux), the pages exist but cant be accessed, the

```
 [[:informatique:angouleme:inventaire_licences|Inventaire Licences]]
```

the link state that the page exist but all i get is 'this page doesn't exist yet' i see nothing wierd with &do=debug i got no error message.

Note that it workds to copy paste data repo or pages repo. it works even if the sitmap isn't updated.

the
      `$html_output = ob_get_clean();
      trigger_event('TPL_CONTENT_DISPLAY', $html_output, 'ptln');`

is returning me the generic answer when he cant find the file i want him to show

i wish to know what is going wrong, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel pretty stupid about it, when passing from a windows server to a Unix server i forget the caps handling are different and so i bad references to my namespaces where my files had caps and dokuwiki biuld all the links without

Answer (score 0):

The pages might have different permission which the www-data can't access. 
Did you check your server error logs? It  will give you more information about the exact problem.
Also, try the [searchIndex plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:searchindex)